# Set a Range with Loop

Tags: excel, vba, range

Let's say I have two columns with values:

```
A1      B1    
A2      B2    
A3      B3
```

I want to be able to loop each row (way more than this) and set a range such so that I can combine cells like so:

```
A1      B1    
A1      B2    
A1      B3    
A2      B1    
A2      B2    
A2      B3    
A3      B1    
A3      B2    
A3      B3
```

Is there a way that I can set ranges using `Set Range(DesiredRange) = A1,B1:B3` to get a range for each row just like below so that I match A1 with every cell in B1:B3?

I was thinking of trying to set a range using an indirect reference like

`Set Range = A1,  B1:B3`

to get this result for the range:

```
A1     B1    
A1     B2     
A1     B3
```

I want to minimize loops.  I am thinking if you can add to each cell in a range then may be you can set I range similarly, but I am not sure if it will work.

Comment: With vba, the only way is with loops.  But use variant arrays instead of the ranges when doing the loops and it will be quick.  But there are formulas that will do this also.  See here: https://superuser.com/questions/1350077/excel-every-combination-of-column-a-and-column-b-into-column-d-and-e/1350079#1350079

Answer (score 0):

I know you wrote that you want to minimize loops, but this really is classic nested loops.  What you want to do is loop through the `A` column, and for each `A`, loop through the `B` column.  In VBA it would look something like this:

```
row = 1
For i = 1 To Range("A1:A3").Count
    For j = 1 To Range("B1:B3").Count
        Range("C" & row).Value = Range("A" & i)
        Range("D" & row).Value = Range("B" & j)
        row = row + 1
    Next
Next
```